# How to build database for development environment?

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I have aws rds aurora database for the production environment. And I have to build a database for the development environment.

I tried it by using aws database migration service(DMS), snapshot, mysqldump.

First, DMS didn't support migrating `Auto_Increment` column and `Indexes`. But I need them.

Second, Snapshot overwrite production database's user data(MySQL user data - using when connecting to MySQL) to the development database. And I want to maintain them differently.

Last, mysqldump is so slow and I concerned about mysqldump may cause down performance to production database.

So, I'm looking for the other way.

The below things are what I want:

1. Every information(w/o MySQL user data) such as `Auto_Increment`, `Indexes` are must be migrated.
2. Development environment database is must be sync to production database(reset and re-migrate) every day automatically.
3. Migration process as faster and lower downing performance as possible is the best.

Does anyone know how to build it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Using an AWS DMS task, you can specify what schema to migrate and the type of migration.

[The page should look similar to the following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRQPC.png)

2. Amazon RDS automatically creates a primary
   DB Instance and synchronously replicates the data to a standby instance in a different
   Availability Zone (AZ). Each AZ runs on its own physically distinct, independent
   infrastructure, and is engineered to be highly reliable.
3. Yes you can. Migrations are among the most time-consuming tasks handled by the database
   administrators (DBAs). Although the task becomes easier with the advent of
   managed migration services such as the AWS Database Migration Service (AWS
   DMS), many large-scale database migrations still require a custom approach
   due to performance, manageability, and compatibility requirements.

Extra

*Amazon RDS provides high availability and failover support for DB instances using Multi-AZ- deployments.

*ElastiCache improves the performance of your database through caching query results

Comment: I tried DMS but it didn't support to migrate indexes and auto increment columns. And I need them.

Comment: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=237083